# How to run Java at design time

Tags: anylogic

Sometimes it costs a lot of time on drawing space markups if the network is complex.

I wonder if there is a way to run Java at design time like Marcos in other software. For example, adding a path manually, and create multiple nodes on the path programmatically, then adjust some of the nodes manually if needed.

I don't find sort of terminal or console to write Java at design mode. Instead, I found agent has **Additional class code** with **Library developer mode** enabled. From the document it says typically developers use this code to override things of agents. I thought it can be used to run my Java code on instantized or override functions generated by AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI. But it seems only allow me to add properties or functions to class that can only used in runtime.

Comment: You can programmatically draw networks and space markups, no problem. This should help: https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/dynamically-adding-model-presentations-to-make-navigation-during-editing-faster-in-anylogic

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks for your suggestion. But I am looking for a way to do this at design time, means before simulation starts. Because I want to reduce time on drawing hundreds of shapes by using code, also to modify the code-gen shapes manually for those special cases hard to write in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write code that draws your network for you at design time.

Either you draw it manually at design time or you write code that draws it for you at the start of the runtime (see https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/dynamically-adding-model-presentations-to-make-navigation-during-editing-faster-in-anylogic ).

You can also mix'n'match: draw some and expand on it with coded shapes.

However, you can not write code that displays your network at design time, no